# Angular 7 doesn't render bootstrap control

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular7

I am creating a Simple system that will need to browse a picture.

I am using paper-dashboard bootstrap admin panel

which can be found below:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/paper-dashboard

Then i need to add a file browser functionality like the screenshot below which i found on w3school

[image]

But it doesn't work or render properly on my Angular application. In order to check if the bootstrap code is working correctly. I created a dummy html file and it rendered correctly just like in the screenshot.

But this is how it is rendered

[image]

But i have the `bootstrap.min.css` in the `angular.json` file

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/paper-dashboard/assets/css/paper-dashboard.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js"
            ],
```

But if i import the `bootstrap.min.css` in the `style.scss`

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

and remove it in the styles array

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/paper-dashboard/assets/css/paper-dashboard.css"
            ],
```

It became like this. The navigation is not rendered properly.

[image]

What may have caused this in the Angular? I am from wpf. And i am doing self study with angular 7 and asp.net core 2. So i really don't have a clear understanding what is happening with the stlye.

Thank you.

Comment: Any collision with your styles? have you customized a tags, for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see is that you are importing the bootstrap from

```
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Meaning that you installed bootstrap as an separate package, which is most likely the newest version - `v4.3.1`

The [paper-dashboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paper-dashboard) is using Bootstrap `v3.3.5`, so you have a version missmatch. ([Check it here](https://github.com/misak113/paper-dashboard/blob/master/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css))

The possible solutions are:

- npm install bootstrap@3.3.5 - it will replace your current bootstrap installation with 3.3.5 version
- change your import to match the path of `bootstrap.min.css` located in `paper-dashboard package`
- manually update the dashboard to match the newest version.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. It help me solve the problem.